# How do I use cut with standard input

Tags: cygwin, cut

I am trying to cut the second column of a tab delimited pasted text. I want to use the cut command so that a program automatically feeds the table via stdin. I have done this sort of thing before with a command like 'column -t'.

when I type 'column -t' in a terminal, it immediately returns a fixed-width table after pasting text in the command line and pressing CTRL-D.

the command 'cut -f2 -' doesn't do that and I'm not sure what I need to do to make it return output after pressing CTRL-D.

Also, note that I'm trying to do this via cygwin. I don't know that it matters, but just FYI.

Any ideas?

Ted

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
cut -f2 | xargs -0
```

My input had backslashes and that proved problematic if I didn't use -0, just so that it doesn't try to interpret '\'.

I don't know why cut doesn't return the output right away. I had to somehow use xargs to get it to print it for me.